# How can I UV map a very complex model?

Tags: texturing, uv

i am doing a project in which i have to create different models of the same object to make it appear to be made of different materials. To do so, i believe i need to UV unwrap such model, which is composed of thousands of triangles. I am new to blender, so at the moment i am using the seams island technique, but my problem is that since is a complex model there are not many places to cut which are not visible, therefore once i apply the textures to the uv mapping the cuts are very much noticeable in the object. Do you have any advice on how to overcome this problem? I will attach some images of the object so that you can better understand what i mean.
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me[image: front][image: side1][image: side2][image: up][image: down]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your use case is, but ideally you would create a model with a clean topology first. This greatly helps with UV unwrapping. With regard to seams, this can be overcome by texture painting with takes the seams into consideration. Would this be an option for you?

Comment: The sort answer is you should try to avoid it. There are retopology tools available for Blender, some free, some paid for. You can also try other softs like meshlab or instant meshes which have ready made retopology tools

Comment: if you plan to paint it in the 3D view you can simply unwrap with the Smart UV Project mode

Comment: thanks everybody, i already tried using the Smart UV project mode but the result was not good enough. I had not thought of creating a new model with a simpler topology and try then to unwrap this new model, I will try it now! Thank you very much!